# Angular external template directive in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this here block of html, say: `<div>{{myVar}}</div>`. This block of code is on a lot of pages in a lot of places. The designer from time to time decides to randomly change the way the block looks and what it contains so i have to every page in every place to redo the blocks of code -> BAD!

The solution would be put that block of code in a directive and modify it in one place only. Now said block of code is quite complex markup wise so i'm inclined to put it in a separate page and do a `templateURL`reference (for ease of editing), but the drawback is that in every place, the directive would sit in an `ng-repeat` and i'm not sure if angular does a HTTP request for that separate page, where the directive would sit, every time it runs into that directive.

My questions are therefore these:

1) Does Angular do a http request every time it runs into that directive? - is there an option for this not to happen, if it does?

2) What other drawbacks could i run into, if i place it in a separate page?

3) What's the rule of thumb for placing the directive in a separate file.

4) When do you know if you're "overdirectivising" your markup?

Comment: I'm pretty sure angular caches any templates after first use so it wouldn't do a http request each time. We put a lot of resuable stuff into directives and they are often in separate files, no issues yet!

Comment: I did decide to go with that route after a bit of testing. Looks alright so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. It gets the template once, put it in a cache, and gets it from the cache for all subsequent occurrences of the directive. Of course, if the app is reloaded (i.e. the page is refreshed, the template will be reloaded. But even then, unless you explicitely prohibit it, the browser should have it in its own cache.
2. I don't see any.
3. I usually do it when the template is too large to be comfortably put inside a JS string literal. Note that you could also put it in a separate file, but embed it in the JavaScript code at build time, if you really don't want an additional HTTP request to load its template.

Comment: Thanks, what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Angular fetches the template once and keeps in the cache and serves it from there.
So there is only one http call.

So if you wan't to avoid it you will have to use a string.

And you can do something better here.
Spicify the dummy URL in the directive. And create the template string somewhere.

And in module.run inject $templatecache service and call:

```
$templatecache.put('url',templateString);
```

Now your directive will behave its reading from the URL. but you are actually specifying the string at module level.

"This way you can specify all your template string at one place. No need to keep them with directive."

Comment: Hmm.. this is definitely interesting.